# table with siunitx - alignment on precision mode

Tags: tables, siunitx, alignment

[image]

In a *test* on making tables, i use the cool package `siunitx` for having some defined precision on values after the comma and to aligning these values on the *dot* in the middle column but unfortunately, it is doing some alignment on the text `Val 2`, the `$\beta$` remained untouched. Does the number `2` being considered as a value for siunitx, even with the text before  as it was like a 2.00 ?
or do i have to create a separate table for the first line (Val 1 ... Val 3) - not convinced...

here is my code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{amsmath}


% le package qui pemet de définir des unités et leur affichage
\usepackage{siunitx} % Required : alignement des valeurs etc.
\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
    round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}

\begin{document}

%exemples de tableau
\noindent\begin{cursive}Des tableaux:\end{cursive}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}

    \label{tab:table1}
        
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % Alignements: left, center, right
            \textbf{Val 1} & \textbf{Val 2} & \textbf{Val 3}\\
            $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
            \hline
            1 & 1110.1 & a\\
            2 & 10.1 & b\\
            3 & 23.113231 & c\\
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Valeurs basiques}

\vspace{1cm}    

    \label{tab:table2}
    
    \begin{tabular}{l|S|r} % c devient S ==> unitsx
        \textbf{Val 1} & \textbf{Val 2} & \textbf{Val 3}\\
        $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
        \hline
        1 & 1110.1 & a\\
        2 & 10.1 & b\\
        3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{Valeurs alignées et arrondies}
  
    \end{center}
  \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want the column head to be centred, add a pair of braces around it.

Comment: As Bernard pointed it out, replace the first two rows of the second table with `\textbf{Val 1} & {\textbf{Val 2}} & \textbf{Val 3}\\ $\alpha$ & {$\beta$} & $\gamma$ \\`, then you will get the centering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you need to define `table-format` to number of decimal digits which you like to show in table, in your case `table-format=4.2`
- column headers, which are not numbers and should be centered in text, should be enclosed in curly braces
- labels for tables had to be after caption

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% le package qui pemet de définir des unités et leur affichage
\usepackage{siunitx} % Required : alignement des valeurs etc.
\sisetup{   % this is now globally set, you ma consider to move it inside table
    round-mode      = places, % Rounds numbers
    round-precision = 2, % to 2 places
}

\begin{document}
%exemples de tableau
\noindent\begin{cursive}Des tableaux:\end{cursive}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % Alignements: left, center, right
\textbf{Val 1} & \textbf{Val 2} & \textbf{Val 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
    \hline
1 & 1110.1      & a\\
2 & 10.1        & b\\
3 & 23.113231   & c\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Valeurs basiques}
\label{tab:table1}
   
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{l|S[table-format=4.2]|r}             % <---
\textbf{Val 1}  & {\textbf{Val 2}} & \textbf{Val 3}  \\  % <---
$\alpha$}       & {$\beta$}        & $\gamma$        \\  % <---
    \hline
1 & 1110.1      & a\\
2 & 10.1        & b\\
3 & 23.113231   & c\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Valeurs alignées et arrondies}
\label{tab:table2}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [@Zarko] is this instruction `S[table-format=4.2]` a replacement of `\sisetup{ ...` and then the package siunitx is completely useless here... ?

Comment: @FannyMae, no. With `sisetup{...}` in preamble, you defined `siunitx` features globally (for whole document), with `S[table-format=4.2]` is defined column format for this particular column, which also consider global settings. See my comment at \sisetup.